# How this isomorphism $\frac{(\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})[x]}{(x+2)} \cong \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ is achieved?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

In these [question1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1296379/cardinality-of-quotient-ring-mathbbz-6x-2x4) [question2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1321589/number-of-elements-in-the-quotient-ring-mathbbz-6-x-langle-2x-4-rangle), I didn't understand the isomorphism $$\frac{(\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})[x]}{(x+2)} \cong \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$$.

Can anyone elaborate on these. I need to understand it properly. Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to construct an isomorphism $\frac{(\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})[x]}{(x+2)} \cong \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ you can construct an epimorphism $\varphi \colon (\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})[x] \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ whose kernel is $(x + 2)$. Since $x + 2$ must be in $\ker(\varphi)$, you don't have much choice - you must send $x$ to $-2 = 1$ (and $1$ to $1$). Thus, define $\varphi(p(x)) := p(1)$ and check that this is indeed a ring epimorphism with $\ker(\varphi) = (x + 2)$.

Comment: I am unable to see the surjection, can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: $\varphi(a) = a$ (where $a \in \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ is considered as an element in the ring $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ and also as a constant polynomial element in the ring $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}[x]$).